# magento how to change the default store in multi store setup

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, stores

I have a multi store setup and i want to change the default shop domain to one of the other stores
ie the default domain is `abc.com` and i have `bcd.com` as a store and `efg.com` as a store.

I want to drop `abc.com` and make `efg.com` the default store leaving only `efg.com` and `bcd.com` as the stores.

Answer (score 3):

You can set default store from admin

```
Go to Admin -> System -> Manage Stores
```

Click on `Store Name` second column and you can change default store from `Default Store View` dropdown.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input, what i have done is put a redirect on abc.com to efg.com  That does the trick nicely, do not know what will happen when abc.com domain name expires will wait and see

Comment: If you don't need to separate the stores by domain, why not just update the base URL on the default store to the new domain? Then traffic to the new domain will show that store.

Comment: This did not work for me... have no other option under `Default Store View`, however do have another option under `Root Category` to set as the Default Category, had no effect and Still showing the 2nd store under `Default Store View`.. still trying to find a solution